# Cucumber-jvm: Clash between Cucumber Hook and TestNG Hook

Tags: testng, cucumber-jvm

I have implement TestNG hook using @BeforeTest annotation and Cucumber hoo using @Before annotation but there is an error showing when running the code.

Error:

> [Utils] [ERROR] [Error] java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at Runner.TestRunner.features(TestRunner.java:105)
>
> FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeTest setUp
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   io/cucumber/tagexpressions/TagExpressionParser    at
>   cucumber.runtime.TagPredicate.(TagPredicate.java:23)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   io.cucumber.tagexpressions.TagExpressionParser
>
> FAILED CONFIGURATION: @AfterTest tearDown
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   Runner.TestRunner.tearDown(TestRunner.java:110)

Login.java

```
public class Login {
private PropertiesManager pm;
private ExtentReportManager reportMgr;

public Login() {

}

/*@Before("@p")
public void setUp() {
    pm = PropertiesManager.createInstance();
    reportMgr = ExtentReportManager.createInstance();

}*/
```

}

TestRunner.java

```
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "src/Feature",
        glue = {"Step_Definitions"},
        plugin = {
                "pretty",
                "html:target/cucumber-reports/cucumber-pretty",
                "json:target/cucumber-reports/CucumberTestReport.json",
                "rerun:target/cucumber-reports/rerun.txt"
})
public class TestRunner {
    private TestNGCucumberRunner testNGCucumberRunner;
    private ExtentReportManager reportMgr;
    private PropertiesManager pm;

    @BeforeTest(alwaysRun = true)
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        testNGCucumberRunner = new TestNGCucumberRunner(this.getClass());

        pm = PropertiesManager.createInstance();
        reportMgr = ExtentReportManager.createInstance();

        WebDriverManager.createDriver();
    }

    @Test(groups = "cucumber", description = "Runs Cucumber Feature", dataProvider = "dataProvider")
    public void feature(CucumberFeatureWrapper cucumberFeature) {
        testNGCucumberRunner.runCucumber(cucumberFeature.getCucumberFeature());
    }
}
```

Why there is clash between Cucumber hook and TestNG hook? How to solve it? Thanks.

Comment: There is no clash here. TestNG is just a means to run your cucumber tests. The hooks will be invoked properly. In your case it looks like you are facing some `ClassNotFoundException` due to a messed up CLASSPATH. You would need to edit your question and show us how are you managing your CLASSPATH. Please share the build file (`build.gradle/pom.xml/build.xml`)

Comment: What jar is missing from my classpath?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://jar-download.com/?detail_search=g%3A%22io.cucumber%22+AND+a%3A%22tag-expressions%22+AND+v%3A%221.1.1%22&a=tag-expressions)

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by adding tag-expression.jar into build path.